# Wheel-graph with minimal spoke-weight sum centered at a planar-euclidean point

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, discrete-geometry

**Questions:**

- Given a set $\mathcal{P}$ of points in the Euclidean plane, what is the complexity of finding for a given point $p_i$ *inside* the convex hull $\mathrm{CH}\left(\mathcal{P}\right)$ the set $\lbrace q_{ij}\rbrace\subseteq\mathcal{P}\setminus p_i\ $ that minimizes $\sum\limits_{j}\left\|q_{ij}-p_i\right\|$ and for which every line through $p_i$ has points from  $\lbrace q_{ij} \rbrace$ to both sides?
- is the subgraph induced by the edge-set set $\lbrace\lbrace p_i, q_{ij}\rbrace\rbrace$ connected?

remark:

$\bigcup\limits_i\bigcup\limits_j (p_i,q_{ij})$ partitions the convex-combination of $\mathcal{P}$ into convex polygonal regions whose minimum-weight triangulation together with the edges of the convex hull $\mathrm{CH}(\mathcal{P})$ and $\bigcup\limits_i\bigcup\limits_j (p_i,q_{ij})$ may yield a good approximation of $\mathcal{P}$'s minimum-weight triangulation.

Comment: I think you mean $\cal{P} \setminus p_i$? And I don't see the role of the index $j$. Could you explain?

Comment: the index was missing; icorrected that. I decided to use the double index because just using$\lbrace q_j\rbrace$ for the spoke-vertices would not allow to identify the center-point from a set in the collection of all those sets for agiven pointset; if there are better ways o express what I describe, I will be glad to reformulate.

Comment: The sum should be for $j$.

Comment: Am I right with my observation that the sets you‘re looking for have size 3?

Comment: @PatrickSchnider yes, you are right, So the question about the complexity, resp. most efficient algorithm remains. I have some ideas that I will post.

Answer (score 1):

That should actually be a seen as comment:

It appears as an $O(n^2)$ is possible:
suppose $q_{ij}, q_{ik}$ are given and $\varphi(q_{ij})=0^\circ$ and $0^\circ\lt\varphi(q_{ik})\le 180^\circ$ then the 3rd point must satisfy $180^\circ\lt\varphi(q_{ih})\le 180^\circ+\varphi(q_{ik})$.
Here $\varphi(q_{ik})$ is the angle of that point in a polar coordinate system with $p_i$ as the origin and a suitably chosen reference direction.

So we are looking for the nearest point in an angular range; that however amounts to a range minimum query that can be answered in [$O(1)$ time per query and $O(n)$ preprocessing](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/78931).
A further improvement would be to determine the halfplane through $p_i$ that contains the fewest elements of $\lbrace q_{ij}\rbrace$ and iterate over the pairs in that set.